# How can I append multiple li after first li using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JSON array, in which you can see each activity array has a child array.

```
{
   "status":true,
   "activities_array":[
      {
         "app":"app name 1",
         "country":"Tunisia",
         "count":10,
         "child_activities":[
            {
               "username":"user name 23",
               "user_id":123,
            },
            {
               "username":"user name 23",
               "user_id":324,
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "app":"app name 2",
         "country":"United Arab Emirates",
         "count":6,
         "child_activities":[
            {
               "username":"user name 1l2",
               "user_id":223,
            },
            {
               "username":"user name 13",
               "user_id":1212,
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying following, but not getting correct html

```
response.activities_array.forEach((activities) => {
    $('#winner-list-by-countries').append(activities.map(activity => {
        return `<ul id="winners-list" class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item active">${activities.app} - ${activities.country}<span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ $activity['count'] }}</span></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item OE-background-color">
                        <span class="text-style">Rank # ${activity.index} </span><br />
                        <span class="text-style">Name: ${activity.username} </span><br /> 
                        <span class="text-style">UserId: ${activity.user_id} </span><br />
                    </li>
            </ul>`;
    }));
});
```

I want to append all li after appending the first li, as you can see first has a `list-group-item active` class. Can someone kindly guide me about it? I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append your first `li` inside your `ul` tag and then use `list-group:last` to append rest `lis` inside last added `ul` tag.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose array look like this..
var response = {
  "status": true,
  "activities_array": [{
      "app": "app name 1",
      "country": "Tunisia",
      "count": 10,
      "child_activities": [{
          "username": "user name 23",
          "user_id": 123,
        },
        {
          "username": "user name 23",
          "user_id": 324,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "app": "app name 2",
      "country": "United Arab Emirates",
      "count": 6,
      "child_activities": [{
          "username": "user name 1l2",
          "user_id": 223,
        },
        {
          "username": "user name 13",
          "user_id": 1212,
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

response.activities_array.forEach((activities) => {
  //append first li ..
  $("#winner-list-by-countries").append(`<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item active">${activities.app} - ${activities.country}<span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">${activities.count}</span></li></ul>`)
  //find last ul added append rest li there
  $('#winner-list-by-countries .list-group:last').append(activities.child_activities.map((activity, index) => {
    return `<li class="list-group-item OE-background-color"><span class="text-style">Rank # ${index+1} </span><br /><span class="text-style">Name: ${activity.username} </span><br /><span class="text-style">UserId: ${activity.user_id} </span><br /> </li>`;
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="winner-list-by-countries">
</div>
```